# Can I say 'I will keep your heart from the fall'

Tags: phrase-request, figurative-language

Can I say in the poem: "I will keep your heart from the fall"?
Or "I will save your heart from the fall'?
Of course, it's indirect meaning.

Comment: Poetic license means that you can use any wording that is understandable. In normal usage however you are unlikely to find "from the fall" used this way. Rather "from falling". keep vs. save does not change this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to a *particular* fall, then yes, you can say:

> I will keep your heart from *the fall*.

But if you don't have a particular fall in mind, and the meaning you want to convey is that you will take care so that the person's heart never falls, you can say:

> I will keep your heart from *falling*.

P.S. So you want to ask, "Can I say in *a* poem..." or "... in *my* poem", because we, the readers|listeners, don't know which poem you are referring to when you say "*the* poem". After you have made clear to us which poem you have in mind (e.g "my poem"), then you can begin to say "the poem".